# Why do I keep getting VBA Overflow Error 6 in calculating PVann?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a calculator (I made a User form) that calculates the PVann. I made a similar macro that works the formula is:

```
    Dim pmt As Integer
    Dim i As Double
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim a As Double
    pmt = Range("C2").Value
    i = Range("C3").Value
    n = Range("C4").Value
    a = (pmt * (1 + (1 - (1 + i) ^ -n) / i))
```

code for calculate button in the User form

```
Private Sub calculate_Click()

Dim pmtInput As Integer
Dim iInput As Double
Dim nInput As Integer
Dim totalOutput As Double

totalOutput = pmtInput * (1 + (1 - (1 + iInput) ^ -nInput) / iInput)


End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work if you change those Integers to Doubles?

Comment: In `calculate_Click`, how are you assigning values to the variables `pmtInput`, `iInput`, and `nInput`?

Comment: No integers to doubles doesn't work.. when I do pmtInput.value it does not work: compile error invalid qualifier

Comment: A variable assignment would look like `pmtInput = ....` (no `.Value` anywhere). Where are you getting the values for these variables from?

Comment: They are coming from the text inputs from the User Form

Comment: @mabil So this input values are global variables, or how do they get the values from the textboxes?

Comment: so I thought if I named the textbox (through properties) I would be able to get the values from there, whatever the user inputted in the textbox. https://youtu.be/i7gysQk7Bd0 this is the video I followed